AT25SF081 FLASH device Status register CS
My confusion is about the waveform they have described in Figure 10-1 on the AT25SF081 Flash Datasheet. I am looking at the Read Register Command 05h.
Here is the question:

It looks like CS is set to Low, then a SCK cycle is skipped, and after this the SI operations begins. Is this correct?


You should also consult Figure 13-1 Serial input timing.  That figure shows the clock (SCK) as free-running, which means that it is toggling both when CS is high and low.  This is one operating mode of SPI.
Another mode is when the clock is gated.  In this mode, SCK does not toggle while CS is high; it only toggles while CS is low.
Figure 10-1 shows SCK as a dashed line at first because it indicates that is doesn't matter if the clock was toggling or not when CS was high.  The important thing is that the CSLS setup timing requirement is met.
The first SCK rising edge after CS goes low is used to sample the SI data input pin (assuming CSLS is met).
